# Compiling vim with xterm_clipboard on CentOS 6.6

Tags: vim, centos, centos6

I have a minimal-install CentOS 6.6, with `Desktop` added afterwards. I'd like to compile the latest `vim` with `xterm_clipboard`.

I did the following

1. Installed `*-devel` packages

   ```
   yum install ruby perl-devel python-devel ruby-devel \
     perl-ExtUtils-Embed ncurses-devel libX11 libX11-devel \
     libXtst-devel libXtst libXt-devel libXt libSM-devel libSM \
     libXpm libXpm-devel
   ```

   That didn't work.
2. Next I tried using `groupinstall`

   ```
   yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" \
     "Fonts" "General Purpose Desktop"
   ```

   No luck either.

**After** each of the above steps, I did

```
make clean

./configure --with-features=huge --enable-perlinterp \
  --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp --with-x=yes \
  --enable-gui=auto
```

and then

```
grep X11 src/auto/config.h
```

But everytime I see

```
/* #undef HAVE_X11 */
```

Forcing a `sudo make install`, and then `vim --version` confirms that I don't have `xterm_clipboard` (the output shows `-xterm_clipboard`).

Could you all please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of my issue is

```
make distclean
./configure ...
```

I only did `make clean` after installing the groups, and various packages. It is not "clean" enough, the config-files are not completely restored to the initial state.

I hope this helps others with the same issue.